How to prove that multiplication of impartial games well-defined?
It is well known that the definition of surreal multiplication can be generalized to all games, though the definition is not well-defined for all games.
Conway has proved that multiplication is well-defined for surreal numbers, and I have known that multiplication is also well-defined for impartial games. Although I have validated small cases of this by computer, I can't prove it by induction.

To show multiplication is well-defined, you need to show, for any impartial games $G_1,G_2$, and $H$ such that $G_1=G_2$, that $G_1\times H=G_2\times H$. Equivalently, adding $G_2\times H$ to both sides (and using $X+X=0$ for all impartial games $X$), we can prove that
$$
G_1\times H+G_2\times H=0,
$$
which means we must show that $G_1\times H+G_2\times H$ is a $P$-position. We prove this by induction on $G_1,G_2,H$.
We must show that every move on $G_1\times H+G_2\times H$ has a winning response. Without loss of generality, consider a move on the $G_1\times H$ component. Every such move is to a game of the form
$$
(G_1'\times H+G_1\times H'+G_1'\times H')+G_2\times H,\tag1
$$
for some option $G_1'$ of $G_1$ and some option $H'$ of $H$.
Since $G_1=G_2$, we know that $G_1+G_2$ is a $P$-position, implying $G_1'+G_2$ is an $N$-position. There is some winning move on $G_1'+G_2$; there are two cases to consider.

Suppose the winning move on $G_1'+ G_2$ is on the $G_2$ component, to a position $G_1'+G_2'$ where $G_2'$ is an option of $G_2$. On $(1)$, the winning response will be on the $G_2\times H$ component, expanding it into $G_2'\times H+G_2\times H'+G_2'\times H'$. The result is
$$
G_1'\times H+G_1\times H'+G_1'\times H'+(\color{blue}{G_2'\times H+G_2\times H'+G_2'\times H'})
\\= (G_1'\times H+G_2'\times H)+(G_1\times H'+G_2\times H')+(G_1'\times H'+G_2'\times H')
$$
By induction, we know that $G_1'\times H+G_2'\times H$ and $G_1\times H'+G_2\times H'$ and $G_1'\times H'+G_2'\times H'$ are all zero, so their sum is zero as well.

Suppose the winning move on $G_1'+G_2$ is on $G_1'$ component, to a position $G_1''+ G_2$, for an option $G_1''$ of $G_1'$. Since $G_1''+G_2=0$, we have $G_1''=G_2$, which further means $G_1=G_1''$.
In this case, the winning response on $(1)$ is to move on the $G_1'\times H$ component, expanding it into $G_1''\times H+G_1'\times H'+G_1''\times H'$. The result is
$$
(\color{blue}{G_1''\times H+G_1'\times H'+G_1''\times H'})+G_1\times H'+G_1'\times H'+G_2\times H
\\
=(G_1''\times H+G_2\times H)+(\color{gray}{G_1'\times H'+G_1'\times H'})+(G_1\times H'+G_1''\times H')
$$
Again, all three parenthesized components in the above sum are zero, by induction, so this is zero.



Thanks! After reading your proof, I've also made another solution which proves the lemma "$G\times H||0$ if and only if $G||0$ and $H||0$" by similar induction.

Happy to help :^) A good way to show appreciation for an answer on MSE is to mark it as "accepted", by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Best wishes in your studies of combinatorial game theory.
